# Norm and boundness of a generic operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I need a some guidance through this particular problem: let $V$ be the space of functions $f:R \to R$ such that $\int_Rf^2(x)dx<+\infty$ and $\int_Rx^2f^2(x)dx<+\infty$

Consider on $V$ the product $\langle f,g \rangle:=\int_Rf(x)g(x)dx+\int_Rx^2f(x)g(x)dx$ which induces on $V$ the norm $||f||_V:=\langle f,f\rangle^{1/2}$

Finally, let $T: V \to R$ the linear operator defined as: $$T(f):=\int_Rfdx$$

The questions are to prove that $T$ is bounded and to calculate its norm. I have a general idea of the direction towards which I should move, but I'm unsure on how and when to use the data I've been given. I'm trying to understand the reasoning behind what I should be doing, and this is what I have:

To prove that $T$ is bounded (I think) I need to show that $|T(f)|_R<\infty$

We have $$|T(f)|_R=\bigg| \int_Rf(x)dx \bigg|$$

Now, I'm pretty sure I can write $$\bigg| \int_Rf(x)dx \bigg| \le\int_R|f(x)|dx$$
even if, in all honesty, I don't remember where this is from. Now, I know from the data I've been given that the norm inside that integral is $$\langle f, f\rangle^{1/2}=\biggl(\int_Rf^2(x)dx+\int_Rx^2f^2(x)dx \bigg)^{1/2}=\bigg( \int_R(1+x^2)f^2(x)dx \bigg)^{1/2}$$ on $V$.

And that's where I get stuck. I don't know where to go from here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|\int f(x) dx| \leq \int \frac  1 {\sqrt {1+x^{2}}} (|f(x)|\sqrt {1+x^{2})}dx$. By Holder's inequality this gives $|Tf| \leq (\int \frac 1 {1+x^{2}} dx)^{1/2} \|f\|$ so $\|T\| \leq \sqrt {\pi}$. To show tht this value is attained on the unit disk just take $f(x)=\frac 1 {\sqrt {\pi} \sqrt {1+x^{2}}}$. Hence $\|T\| = \sqrt {\pi}$.

Comment: May I please ask to elaborate a little more on the first equation? How do you get from left to right? Thank you!

Comment: @Silence Just multiplied and divided  $f(x)$ by $\sqrt {1+x^{2}}$. There was  a minor error with absolute value missing.

Comment: Is that simple manipulation to get $f(x)(1+x^2)^{1/2}$ which under the integral becomes $||f||_V$? Then you deal with the consequence which is the arctan?

Comment: @Silence Yes, exactly. That step is crucial to finding the  norm.

Comment: Oh, so that's an actual method. I'd never encountered it before, that makes a lot of sense. Thank you very much once again for your patience!